# Realm database file encryption swift

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

I'm working on mobile application, using Realm as local database I have tried to encrypt the data inside the file but it's to much to handle.

I'm wondering if I can encrypt the Realm database file? if it possible how to do it?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Encrypting realm is covered in the [Getting Started Guide: Encrypting Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#encryption). Did you take a look at that?

Comment: from Realm doc: https://docs.realm.io/sync/using-synced-realms/encrypting-realms

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
// Generate a random encryption key
var key = Data(count: 64)
_ = key.withUnsafeMutableBytes { bytes in
  SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 64, bytes)
}

// Open the encrypted Realm file

let config = Realm.Configuration(encryptionKey: key)

do {

  let realm = try Realm(configuration: config)

  // Use the Realm as normal

  let dogs = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("name contains 'Fido'")

} catch let error as NSError {

  // If the encryption key is wrong, `error` will say that it's an invalid database

  fatalError("Error opening realm: \(error)")

}
```